# Issues with two different column sizes

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

**I'm bringing this website here because Wordpress.stackexchange.com said it wasn't specific enough... Please help!**

I have a website [**here**](http://azeverything.com/).

I am trying to resize the center column and I'm having a hard time. I once had everything correct, but a client went in and updated something and that updated the CSS and I'm all screwed up somewhere. Just not sure where.

**Here's the CSS for the sidebar section...**

```
/** Sidebar *********************************/ 
.side-wrap {
 width: 205px;
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 z-index:1;
}

.side-wrap.left.border.bottom {float:left;background:url(images/content-border-d.png) right bottom no-repeat;}


.sidebar-content {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 height:auto;
 width: 205px;
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 z-index:1;
}


.sidebar-content ul li.sidebartitle a { background:none;}
.sidebar-content ul li.widget {clear:both;}
.sidebar-content ul li.widget:after { content: "."; display: none; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
.side-wrap .border-wrap.left .sidebar-content ul .widget {padding-right:5px; width:335px; }
.side-wrap .border-wrap.right .sidebar-content ul .widget {padding-left:5px; width:200px; }
.sidebar-content ul .widget {padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:5px;}
.sidebar-content li {list-style:none;}

.border-wrap {
 width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 height:auto;
 z-index:0;
 height:100%;
 padding-bottom:25px;
}
```

However, the left sidebar is supposed to be 335px and the right sidebar, at 200px, which is where it's at now.

Answer (score 1):

You have these classes on the left div:

`class="border-wrap right in-full border bottom"`,

it should be:

`class="border-wrap left in-full border bottom"`

As it is this selector is not selecting for anything:

```
.side-wrap .border-wrap.left .sidebar-content ul .widget {
    padding-right:5px; 
    width:335px; 
}
```

Comment: `class="border-wrap right in-full border bottom"` Where would I correct this? It's not in the style sheet? Not sure how to get to the HTML.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I know how to get to your HTML, you could be using any number of systems, but you should probably figure that out.

Comment: It's not a number of systems. It's Wordpress. What you're suggesting is correct and it works when I debug in Chrome. What I can't seem to figure out is how to make the above change in the backend. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I can get your left sidebar to a width of 280px, then it pushes the right sidebar to a new line... Here's a screenshot of that - is this anywhere near your original layout?[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for inner containers**

It looks to me like the div that contains the entire middle section is:

```
<div class="side-wrap  left out-quarter  ">
```

I think the following CSS entry should do the trick:

```
div.side-wrap.left.out-quarter {width:335px;}
div.side-wrap.left.out-quarter .sidebar-content,
div.side-wrap.left.out-quarter .sidebar-content ul li {width:100%;}
```

Put it at the bottom of your CSS file.

Comment: I have it set up the way you suggested right now. It didn't work. Check if you like. I'll leave that up.

Comment: That took care of the width of the outside container. Now you need to address the width of the inner text. See update. If padding isn't what you want, just modify the CSS provided to adjust the padding to meet your needs.